Debian 10 creating /dev/srn device node for SCSI magneto-optical disk drive instead of /dev/sdn
I'm attempting to do raw reads of an old magneto-optical disk in Debian 10 (I can do this in Windows without issues)
I was expecting linux to add the disk as /dev/hdn or /dev/sdn, but it appears to be seeing it as a cdrom (/dev/srn). Here's the relevant lines from dmesg:
[   22.112062] scsi host33: Adaptec AIC7XXX EISA/VLB/PCI SCSI HBA DRIVER, Rev 7.0
              <Adaptec 29160N Ultra160 SCSI adapter>
              aic7892: Ultra160 Wide Channel A, SCSI Id=7, 32/253 SCBs

[   37.472036] scsi host36: Adaptec AIC7XXX EISA/VLB/PCI SCSI HBA DRIVER, Rev 7.0
              <Adaptec 29160N Ultra160 SCSI adapter>
              aic7892: Ultra160 Wide Channel A, SCSI Id=7, 32/253 SCBs

[   38.764112] scsi 36:0:5:0: WORM              LMS      LD 1200E SCSI    0183 PQ: 0 ANSI: 1
[   38.780029] scsi target36:0:5: Beginning Domain Validation
[   38.801822] scsi target36:0:5: Ending Domain Validation
[   41.134286] sr 36:0:5:0: [sr1] scsi-1 drive
[   41.134456] sr 36:0:5:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr1
[   41.134516] sr 36:0:5:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 4
[   41.178402] sr 36:0:5:0: [sr1] unsupported sector size 1024.
[   41.312627] PM: Image not found (code -22)

when I attempt to read from /dev/sr1 using dd bs=1024 if=/dev/sr1 I get 0 records; presumably because /dev/sr1 doesn't accept a 1024 byte block size, but I know that is what the M/O disk is using.
Incidentally, cat /proc/scsi/scsi results in:
Attached devices:
Host: scsi0 Channel: 00 Id: 00 Lun: 00
  Vendor: VMware   Model: Virtual disk     Rev: 2.0 
  Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI  SCSI revision: 06
Host: scsi2 Channel: 00 Id: 00 Lun: 00
  Vendor: NECVMWar Model: VMware SATA CD00 Rev: 1.00
  Type:   CD-ROM                           ANSI  SCSI revision: 05
Host: scsi36 Channel: 00 Id: 05 Lun: 00
  Vendor: LMS      Model: LD 1200E SCSI    Rev: 0183
  Type:   WORM                             ANSI  SCSI revision: 01

is there a way to make linux create a /dev/sdn device file for it rather than a /dev/srn?
